# What is the origin of celibacy for Catholic Priests?

Tags: catholicism, church-history, sexuality, priesthood

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When did the prohibition of marriage for priests in the Catholic church originate?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/4488/when-did-the-prohibition-of-marriage-for-priests-in-the-catholic-church-originat)

When and why did the Vatican decide that Catholic priests should take a vow of celibacy?