# Why  can't the Pope have children?

Tags: catholicism, life-of-jesus, papacy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the basis for clerical celibacy?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1813/what-is-the-basis-for-clerical-celibacy)

Why it is said to be a bad thing since Christians say that God had a Son?
Why do humans deny that to themselves and accept it for God?

Comment: Welcome to Christianity--StackExchange!  What has your research turned up so far?  We welcome all sorts of questions about Christianity, but we prefer "expert" questions.  Feel free to edit your question with evidence that you've put some thought into the question and poked around for possible answers.  (I also edited the question to bring it more in line with our standards.)

Comment: This is also denominational; Your question may relate to Catholicism, but that is not the entire of Christianity.

Answer (score 10):

It's very simple actually. The Pope can't have children because in Western Catholicism, Priests are expected to be unmarried and celibate.

Mary and Joseph had a child despite celibacy, but they were at least married (thus giving Christ a legitimate father). I can't see how someone who cannot have an illegitimate child (celibate) or a miraculous child (not married) would be able to accomplish this, but I suppose that anything is possible through Christ.

Answer (score 2):

The truth is that [there were Popes who had children](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_sexually_active_popes).

> Pope Pius II (1458–1464) had at least two illegitimate children (one in Strasbourg and another one in Scotland), born before he entered the clergy.[10]
>   Pope Innocent VIII (1484–1492) had at least two illegitimate children, born before he entered the clergy.[11] According to the 1911 Encyclopædia Britannica, he "openly practised nepotism in favour of his children".[12] Girolamo Savonarola chastised him for his worldly ambitions.[13] The title Padre della patria (Father of the Fatherland) was suggested for him, precisely with suggestions that he may have fathered as many as 16 illegitimate children.[14]
>   Pope Clement VII (1523–1534) had one illegitimate son before he took holy orders. Academic sources identify him with Alessandro de' Medici, Duke of Florence.[15][16]
>   Pope Gregory XIII (1572–1585) had an illegitimate son before he took holy orders.[17]
>   [edit]Sexually active after receiving Holy Orders
>   Pope Julius II (1503–1513) had at least one illegitimate daughter, Felice della Rovere (born in 1483, twenty years before his election). Some sources indicate that he had two additional illegitimate daughters, who died in their childhood.[18] Furthermore, some (possibly libellous) reports of his time accused him of sodomy. According to the schismatic Council of Pisa in 1511, he was a "sodomite covered with shameful ulcers."[19]

Pope Paul III (1534–1549) held off ordination[20] in order to continue his promiscuous lifestyle, fathering four illegitimate children (three sons and one daughter) by his mistress Silvia Ruffini. He broke his relations with her ca. 1513. There is no evidence of sexual activity during his papacy.[21] He made his illegitimate son Pier Luigi Farnese the first Duke of Parma.[22][23]
Pope Pius IV (1559–1565) had three illegitimate children before his election to the papacy.[24]

> Pope Sergius III (904–911) was supposedly the father of Pope John XI by Marozia, according to Liutprand of Cremona in his Antapodosis,[25] as well as the Liber Pontificalis.[26] However it must be noted that this is disputed by another early source, the annalist Flodoard (c. 894-966), John XI was brother of Alberic II, the latter being the offspring of Marozia and her husband Alberic I. Hence John too may have been the son of Marozia and Alberic I. Bertrand Fauvarque underlines that the contemporary sources backing up this parenthood are dubious, Liutprand being "prone to exaggeration" while other mentions of this fatherhood appear in satires written by supporters of late Pope Formosus.[27]

Now, to be fair, many of these were in 1400's, a time that I suspect even most Catholics would now call the low point of the papacy, especially in theological terms. There were three Popes at one time, all sorts of politicking, and in general, the Papacy was just another earthly Kingdom. (Again, I want to keep stressing even modern Catholics would probably agree with me on this.)

Additionally, the first Pope, Peter, was at least known to be married. (Jesus healed his mother in law, after all).

Celibacy is not a "modern" innovation, but it is clearly post-Biblical.

Comment: What is the wrong of doing sex activities if you are married even you are a pope, why these rules ?!

Comment: I'm pretty sure Paul encouraged celibacy in [1 Cor. 7](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Corinthians%207). Does that count as Biblical?

Comment: @fredsbend you know the difference between preference, encouragement, and command. Check the context.

Comment: @AffableGeek Paul is pragmatic enough to know that if he ordered celibacy on everyone there would be more sexual immorality. "I say this as a concession, not as a command. **I wish that all of you were as I am. But each of you has your own gift from God;** one has this gift, another has that." He is saying, "if you think you can not be married and not sexually sin, then do that."